# How to get more than 100 limit photos in an album on Facebook on iOS app?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Sorry for my poor English and this is my first time using Stack Overflow and don't knows how to make my question easy to read and understand, please forgive me.

I just started to learn Objective-C one week ago and now I'm creating an iOS application to get all Facebook albums and then show all photos in an album to a `UICollectionView` and when select a photo its will display in a `UIImageView`. But I have a problems

**1**

I'm notice that when I choose an album to see its photos, it returns only 25 photos. I tried to set limit like this:

```
- (void)sendRequest
{
    NSString *graphPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@?fields=photos.limit(500)", _albumID];

    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:graphPath parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        NSDictionary* resultDict = (NSDictionary*)result;
        NSDictionary* dict  = [resultDict objectForKey:@"photos"];
        NSArray* array = [dict objectForKey:@"data"];
        for (NSDictionary* innerDict in array) {
            NSString* source = [innerDict objectForKey:@"source"];
            [_datasource addObject:source];
        }
        NSLog(@"dem :%i",_datasource.count);
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    }];
}
```

But its return only max 100 photos even when I set the `limit` to `10000` (my Facebook albums have more than 800 pictures).

**2**

When I choose a picture in any album to show it to UIImageView, it displays. But when I scroll to see other photos and then choose a photo it displays wrong in UIImageView.

Please see the the picture below for more information

[image]

Please help me to solve this problems. Thanks a lot :)

I don't know how to posting code with right format, so anyone can see my source code here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vur575vm9dqykwu/Fb.zip